# Need to show the json value as it is in front end

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Action": {
      "ActionId": "8f5fdb31-46da-4cae-a678-dafcc9c51d19",
      "EmailBodyText": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n<h2>The src Attribute</h2>\n<p>HTML images are defined with the img tag, and the filename of the image source is specified in the src attribute:</p>\n</body>\n</html>"
    }
  },
  "Message": "Success",
  "Status": "Success",
  "Type": 0
}
```

-- Working in Vue js
-- Need to show the EmailBodyText as it is in front end
-- While fetching EmailBodyText from the json and in front end its showing as

```
The src Attribute
HTML images are defined with the img tag, and the filename of the image source is specified in the src attribute:
```

-- Need to show EmailBodyText as the text,means whatever the tags in json need to show their.

```js
var myObj, x;
myObj = {
"EmailBodyText": "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵<body>↵<h2>The src Attribute</h2>↵<p>HTML images are defined with the img tag, and the filename of the image source is specified in the src attribute:</p>↵</body>↵</html>"
};
x = myObj.EmailBodyText;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

shown like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf6vr.png)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: specifically in vue, in vue `{{myObj.EmailBodyText}}` should work fine

Comment: yes.....but i need like this <!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵<body>↵<h2>The src Attribute</h2>↵<p>HTML images are defined with the img tag, and the filename of the image source is specified in the src attribute:</p>↵</body>↵</html>

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Comment: Put it in a <pre> tag?

Comment: use `pre` or `code` tags

Comment: need like this <!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵<body>↵<h2>The src Attribute</h2>↵<p>HTML images are defined with the img tag, and the filename of the image source is specified in the src attribute:</p>↵</body>↵</html>

Comment: So, do you want the rendered HTML, the page generated by that HTML, and not the code show "as is" (the code itself)?

Comment: yes....need to code itself.